# Overload function in C language using _Generic mix function call with constants returning

Tags: c, overloading

I see there are two ways of writing a `_Generic` statement:

A.

```
#define len(x) _Generic((x), char*:f1, int: f2, char: f3, double:f4) (x)
```

I want to underline the **(x)**.

B.

```
#define len(x) _Generic((x), char*:f1(x), int: f2(x), char: f3(x), double:f4)
```

The problem is that in the B case, I got errors:

1. expected char* but argument is of type int
2. incompatible type for argument 1 of f...

How Am I suppose to write this overload if I want to mix functions with constants?

I'm trying to get:

- 1 if the argument is of type char;
- the length of the string if the argument is of type char *;
- the number of decimal digits (possibly increased by one when the argument is negative) if the argument is of type int;
- the length of the string produced by the printf() function using the %f specifier if the argument is of type double.

  ```
   int_len(int number)
   {
       unsigned counter=0;
       if(number < 0)
       {
           counter++;
       }

       while(number)
       {
           counter++;
           number /= 10;
       }
       return counter;
   }
   int char_len(int param)
   {
       return 1;
   }

   int double_len(double param)
   {
       return 10;
   }

   int charptr_len(char* ptr)
   {
       unsigned count=0;
       while(*ptr)
       {
           ptr++;
           count++;
       }
       return count;
   }


   #define len(x) _Generic((x), char*:charptr_len(x), int: int_len(x), char:1, double:double_len(x))

   int main(void) {
       printf("%d\n",len(261321));
       printf("%d\n",len(261.321));
       printf("%d\n",len((char)'x'));
       printf("%d\n",len("A kingdom for a horse!"));
       return 0;
   }
  ```

p.s I know the code might be stupid but I just wanted it to work .

Comment: As you have noticed, *all* generic selection branches, even those not taken, must be valid...

Comment: In the latter case **all** f1(x) and f2(x) and f3(x) must be valid with the given argument.

Comment: p.s I was trying something like this but with no success `#define len(x) _Generic((x), char*:charptr_len(x), int: int_len(x), char:1, double:double_len(x))
`

Comment: Yes. because `charptr_len(261321)` is a constraint violation... even though it is not *evaluated*.

Comment: `The problem is that in the B case` Please show a full [MCVE]. I doubt this macro definition alone gives you any errors.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala how can I do something similar but without the need of all branches to be valid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to get:

Imagine the compiler takes all paths for any input. Whichever path compiler takes, they all have to be "valid" for any input, even if only one expression is used and evaluated and the rest is discarded, they technically have to be "valid".

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define len(x)  _Generic((x), \
    char: 1, \
    char *: (int)strlen((char*)(void*)(uintptr_t)x), \
    int: snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", x), \
    double: snprintf(NULL, 0, "%f", x))

int main() {
    printf("%d\n",len(261321));
    printf("%d\n",len(261.321));
    printf("%d\n",len((char)'x'));
    printf("%d\n",len("A kingdom for a horse!"));
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/rz7e1T). I ended up with the super casts in `strlen` to handle `strlen(261.321)` case - to cast a `double` to a pointer so that compiler doesn't complain. It doesn't matter in `"abc"` case where I hope that the cast do not modify the pointers value. That's why it's easier to develop separate functions for each case. You may also (ab-)use variadic function arguments in generics to easily remove any casts and deal with them inside your functions with `va_arg`s.

(Little self promotion: I recently explored limits of `_Generic` by [developing type-safe-ish printf](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio), with that library it would be just [#define len(x) ysprint(NULL, 0, x)](https://ce.karta.dyzio.pl/z/W34YYo), but I already see that the number of digits after comma in double case is different from `%f` in `printf`).

Comment: is there something you can do in order to have the "overloading" but not let the compiler complain for mismatches? And how doesn `snptrinf` works with `NULL` as first parameter?

Comment: And if you can also explain this `char[sizeof(x)]: (int)sizeof(x)`, why do you need it ?

Comment: does the char[sizeof(x)] really work? Also, that would break for a string literal :P

Comment: Also, I get complaints from the printf arguments! Unfortunately, it is impossible to cast a double to pointer :'D

Comment: But yeah, the `char[sizeof(x)]` doesn't work, you cannot catch an array like this

Comment: `I get complaints from the printf arguments!` And that's why `_Generic((x), int: f1, char: f2)(x)` is preferred or you should be able to cast it all. You could also `_Generic((x), char: f(1, x), int: f(2, x))` by doing `void f(int type, ...)` and then using `va_arg`. | Och, you are right `char[sizeof(x)]` doesn't work, I'll just remove it.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu `is there something you can do in order to have the "overloading" but not let the compiler complain for mismatches?` Use functions like you did. Make `char_len` return 1 and just pass it. Compiler will optimize it away anyway (assuming you make it `static` maybe also `inline`). `how doesn snptrinf works with NULL as first parameter?` [printf cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) Returns the count of characters that _would have been written_ if the pointer was valid.

Comment: why didn't you also used `char *: snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s", x)` for char ?

Comment: I guess to show the casts and because `strlen` is going to be faster. But sure, that's should be fine.